# How can I find a where data is from in SQLite through a query?

Tags: database, sqlite, csv

I have a database file I am using DB Browser for SQLite. I have ran a query found through stack to help me locate a particular value, but when I export the .db tables to csv to try and find the value that exists, I cannot find said value in Excel or notepad++

SELECT "814734315198559" FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
-- Result: 24 rows returned in 12ms

I am filtering almost every column I can find, but I can't seem to find where these values are located.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wont find the value as the value used in the select is a value rather than an identifier (column name). That is the query will return a result set with a single column with the value **"814734315198559"** for every row in the **sqlite_master** table where the type **column** has a value of table.

Likewise if you used :-

```
SELECT "anyoldbvalue" FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';
```

Then 24 rows would be returned in the result set each having a single column with the value of **"anyoldbvalue"**

However, if you used

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';
```

The the query would return 24 rows, each row having a single column where the value would be the respective name of the table in the database (sqlite_master excluded).

e.g. the result (from a testing database) could be :-

[image]

In the above case, if the export includes table names, then they could be found.